# how to change return value type declarations when the method rewrite with decorator in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

```
const Addon = (target, name) => {
  Object.defineProperty(target, name, {
    value() {
      return {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
      };
    },
  });
};

class Test {
  @Addon
  public fn() {
    return {
      a: 1,
    };
  }
}

const test = new Test();

const result = test.fn();

console.log(result.b);
```

thats code, when i call `fn`, it weill return `{a: 1, b: 2}`, if i take `fn.b`, typescript will throw an Error: `Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: number; }'`

though i can use any to pass the error... but thats not a good way...

how can i fix that?

thank

Comment: This is essentially not possible with decorators; [ms/TS#49229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49229) and other related issues show that decorators do not currently modify the types of the things they decorate.  This may eventually be added to the language, but not until after some more fundamental work with decorators takes place (waiting for [ms/TS#50820](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50820) for now).  Does this fully address your question? If so I will write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?